# My UWP DLL using WinRT needs VCRuntime140_app and other dlls to be copied into the same folder as the host app

Tags: visual-c++, dll, uwp, unreal-engine4

I made a Universal Windows dll (to use the Bluetooth LE features in Win10) which is used by a game engine (Unreal), but when I load this dll at runtime it tries to load some required dlls: vcruntime140_app, vccorlib140_app, and msvcp140_app. I'm assuming these are the UWP based VC++ redistributables. I have VC++ Redist. installed but when I run my application it says it's looking for these dlls, and not finding them automatically.

If I copy these dlls from the SXS folder, it all works but obviously I don't want to ship my application with my copy of these dlls; so my question is why isn't it looking in the Windows associated folders for these files. Does a UWP DLL need a manifest specifying its use of the VC++ redistributable? From what I understand the _App suffix is for UWP application use.

Comment: There's no such thing as "UWP based" Visual C++ redists; a redistributable DLL remains unmodified by a specific program using it. My informed guess would be you have the wrong redist installed: 140 is Visual Studio 2015 (v14), not 2017. https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=48145

Comment: Except I have all the redistributions installed, dating back to 2008. I found that the vccorlib140_app and other dlls are only found in the SXS folder, unlike vccorlib140 dlls which are in the System32 folder. From what I gathered on Microsoft forums, the _app dlls must be bundled if you're not going to distribute to the Windows Store.